# MySQL: Cálculo de percentiles

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando calcular el percentil 80 para un tiempo de espera de unas tiendas; es decir, el valor que deja el 80 % de los registros por debajo de él.

He encontrado una solución interesante en un hilo de SO internacional:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38644788/11030842

Y lo he aplicado con éxito a mi caso:

```
SELECT
    t1.na_store AS na_store,
    t1.dt_day AS dt_day,
    t1.qt_waiting_time_s AS qt_waiting_time_s_p_80 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t.id AS id_ticket,
            q.description AS na_store,
            date(t.issue_time) AS dt_day,
            timestampdiff(second, t.issue_time, t.called_in_time) AS qt_waiting_time_s,
            @row_num:= @row_num + 1 AS row_num 
        FROM 
            ticket AS t
                INNER JOIN queue AS q ON t.queue_id = q.id,
            (SELECT @row_num:= 0) AS c
        ORDER BY
            qt_waiting_time_s ASC
    ) AS t1
WHERE
    t1.row_num = round(0.8 * @row_num)
```

Mi problema es que este código permite determinar el P80 para todos los datos, pero ¿si quiero calcular el P80 agrupando por tienda y por día?

Habría que hacer el conteo por tienda y por día en vez de usar un contador global, es decir, conseguir agrupar ya en la subconsulta, pero la verdad es que no sé si es posible.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano, gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Que versión de mysql estás usando?

Comment: La 5.7. Por lo que leí en el hilo que enlazo la 8 tiene ya funciones propias para lidiar con estos asuntos, pero...

Comment: Efectivamente, por eso lo preguntaba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saber cualquier percentil de un conjunto de datos implica:

1. Enumerarlos en orden ascendente
2. Obtener la cantidad total de filas
3. Sobre el total de filas, calcular el porcentaje, si tenemos 100 filas, el 80% debería estar en la fila 80

Esa es la teoría, funciona ya sea sobre el total de filas o bien particionando los datos en grupo. Por el código de tu pregunta, entiendo que estás en una versión de mysql anterior a la 8, por lo que no dispones de `ROW_NUMBER()` que es lo que resuelve fácilmente el punto 1 y lo puede hacer además particionando los grupos por tienda y dia, de modo que hay que buscar una alternativa, que es básicamente algo parecido a lo que ya tienes, pero con las salvedad, que deberemos "reiniciar" el número de fila cada vez que cambie la tienda y el día.

Imaginemos el problema de forma más conceptual, tienes una tabla similar a esto:

```
CREATE TABLE datos
(
  tienda int,
  dia    int,
  tiempo int
);
```

`tienda`, `dia` y `tiempo` son los datos, para generar un enumerador por tiempo ascendente y particionado por `tienda` y `dia`, podemos hacer algo así:

```
set @row_number := 0;
set @anterior := '';

SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @anterior = concat(tienda, '|', dia) THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS Rn,
       @anterior:=concat(tienda, '|', dia) tienda_dia,
       tienda,
       dia,
       tiempo
       FROM datos t
       ORDER BY tienda, dia, tiempo;
```

Una salida posible:

```
Rn  tienda_dia  tienda  dia tiempo
1   1|1 1       1       15
2   1|1 1       1       20
3   1|1 1       1       50
1   1|2 1       2       10
2   1|2 1       2       20
3   1|2 1       2       20
4   1|2 1       2       30
1   2|1 2       1       10
2   2|1 2       1       20
```

Los datos son solo un ejemplo para entender la idea del numerador. Teniendo esto ya hemos resuelto el punto 1, nos queda calcular cual es la cantidad total de filas para cada grupo y luego sí obtener las filas del percentil indicado. A mi criterio, lo más sencillo, es trabajar con tablas temporales:

```
set @row_number := 0;
set @anterior := '';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tienda_dia AS (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @anterior = concat(tienda, '|', dia) THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS Rn,
       @anterior:=concat(tienda, '|', dia) tienda_dia,
       tienda,
       dia,
       tiempo
       FROM datos t
       ORDER BY tienda, dia, tiempo
);
       
       
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tienda_dia_grupos AS (
select tienda_dia,
       max(Rn) MaxRn
       from tienda_dia
       group by tienda_dia
);
```

Tenemos dos tablas, una con cada fila original y su número de orden y otra con el total de filas de cada grupo, nos queda simplemente unirlas mediante un `join` y realizar el filtro deseado:

```
select t.tienda, 
       t.dia,
       t.tiempo
       from tienda_dia t
       inner join tienda_dia_grupos g
                 on t.tienda_dia = g.tienda_dia
       where t.Rn = floor(g.MaxRn * .8);
```

Notas:

- Prefiero usar `floor` por que el criterio de redondeo sería siempre el mismo
- Te dejo también este [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=72a5ffeafe9830a5e585039c77cfcd9e) para ver la idea.

Comment: Al hacer algún cálculo adicional en `tienda_dia_grupos`, como por ejemplo `avg(tiempo) AS tiempo_avg`, luego no es posible mostrar el campo en la última consulta: siempre da un error del tipo `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'g.tiempo_avg' in 'field list'`; ¿a qué se debe?

Comment: A que la columna no existe, o al menos no con ese nombre. ¿está bien que uses el alias, el `g.`? si es una consulta que materializa la columna ya no debes usar el alias sino solo el nombre.

Comment: Hoy desde la oficina funciona con normalidad. Los caminos de la informática son inescrutables. Muchas gracias por todo, Patricio.